# react-material table with typescript shows generic type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-table

I'm trying to run [react-material](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table) under a Typescript project.

Since I'm newbie with Typescript I got some errors I don't know how to solve them.

In this [guest](https://gist.github.com/ZiedHf/1b021ef5c131f2142fcc9de62f088437) I'm trying to create a reusable React component. (Please open the guest to see the full code)

As I said the example above shows some errors, this is an example in the line 48 in homePage :

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<MaterialTableProps<IData>>): KTable<IData>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ title: string; field: string; type: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Column<IData>[]'.
      Type '{ title: string; field: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Column<IData>'.
        Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "boolean" | "time" | "numeric" | "date" | "datetime" | "currency" | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: MaterialTableProps<IData>, context?: any): KTable<IData>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ title: string; field: string; type: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Column<IData>[]'.ts(2769)
```

Why this array shows an error ?

```
columns = [...{
    title: "Birth Place",
    field: "birthCity",
    type: "string" // ERROR ?!
}]
```

Despite the interface defines clearly that type accept string :

```
type?: ('string' | 'boolean' | 'numeric' | 'date' | 'datetime' | 'time' | 'currency');
```

It would be helpful if someone have an idea how to get this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED ! My god it took me so much to handle this typescript errors ...

```
type IType =
  | "string"
  | "boolean"
  | "numeric"
  | "date"
  | "datetime"
  | "time"
  | "currency";
const string: IType = "string";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    field: "name",
    type: string
  },
  {
    title: "Surname",
    field: "surname",
    type: string
  },
  {
    title: "Birth Year",
    field: "birthYear",
    type: string
  },
  {
    title: "Birth Place",
    field: "birthCity",
    // lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa", 1: "Berlin", 2: "Tunis" },
    type: string
  }
];
```

Answer (score 4):

Using primitive string value `string` will be interpreted as string which is not the correct type. 
To solve that cast it to `const`.

```
columns = [...{
    title: "Birth Place",
    field: "birthCity",
    type: "string" as const // ERROR ?!
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` is actually not an acceptable type for the column type:

[image]

I created a PR to fix this but if you are displaying a string, you can just omit the type.